# How to show three panes with highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use highstock to show financial graph,i know there is one example here about two panes of price and volume, my case is somewhat different.

I want to show 3 panes:

pane one to show price with MA indicator;

pane two show volume;

pane three show other indicator such as MACD or KDJ etc.

My code seems not work as following:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Bitcoin Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            ma7 = [],
            ma14 = [],
            dataLength = data.length;

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            ma7.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][4] // the volume
            ]);

            ma14.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                115 // the volume
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ])
        }

        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        var groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]];

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },

            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Bitcoin Graph'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Price'
                },
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: 300,
                height: 100,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            },{       
                title: {
                    text: 'MACD'
                },
                top: 400,           
                height: 50,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'MA7',
                data: ma7,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'MACD',
                data: ma7,
                yAxis: 2,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'KDJ',
                data: ma14,
                yAxis: 2,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And data.json as following:

```
    [[1376366400000, 106.79999, 106.9, 106.62, 106.88991, 86.37460559], [1376370000000, 106.88991, 107.7, 106.6277, 107.7, 678.41676166], [1376373600000, 107.7, 107.7, 106.128, 106.32238, 595.69711545], [1376377200000, 106.32238, 106.9, 106.00001, 106.9, 532.20847672], [1376380800000, 106.9, 106.9, 106.0, 106.49892, 521.89933928], [1376384400000, 106.49892, 106.5, 106.01, 106.10963, 203.36636815], [1376388000000, 106.10963, 106.5, 106.0, 106.47994, 334.59101672], [1376391600000, 106.47994, 106.5, 106.0, 106.29999, 441.57660142], [1376395200000, 106.29999, 106.5, 104.5, 104.70003, 1556.00274696], [1376398800000, 104.70003, 107.5, 104.50952, 105.7222, 940.53385617], [1376402400000, 105.7222, 107.44, 105.71501, 106.068, 169.10705368], [1376406000000, 106.068, 107.45, 106.05029, 106.30934, 220.20452125], [1376409600000, 106.30934, 107.68, 106.21, 107.39986, 1026.0520674], [1376413200000, 107.39986, 107.68, 106.61005, 106.61344, 525.08722011], [1376416800000, 106.61344, 108.567, 106.61234, 108.567, 3349.65882447], [1376420400000, 108.567, 108.67, 108.0, 108.42998, 1077.32326057], [1376424000000, 108.42998, 108.42998, 106.99, 107.09, 514.24768852], [1376427600000, 107.09, 108.85226, 107.09, 107.69363, 944.35661717], [1376431200000, 107.69363, 108.99, 107.69363, 108.5, 1286.18372094], [1376434800000, 108.5, 109.64, 108.5, 109.555, 1556.01199758], [1376438400000, 109.555, 109.555, 108.5, 108.89999, 543.86466322], [1376442000000, 108.89999, 109.0, 108.0, 108.30036, 316.67571515], [1376445600000, 108.30036, 108.97991, 108.0, 108.69799, 275.85851563], [1376449200000, 108.69799, 111.89, 108.21013, 110.80002, 7480.56302089], [1376452800000, 110.80002, 111.89, 110.2, 110.55, 747.81757193], [1376456400000, 110.55, 113.9806, 110.5, 111.98999, 4273.71103807], [1376460000000, 111.98999, 112.49, 111.00186, 112.2, 1090.76643438], [1376463600000, 112.2, 114.0, 112.0, 112.8948, 4114.83393303], [1376467200000, 112.8948, 115.0, 112.15019, 114.41, 3238.67192612], [1376470800000, 114.41, 114.85999, 113.5, 114.499, 1059.25099831], [1376474400000, 114.499, 115.0, 113.5, 113.79999, 3055.65487825], [1376478000000, 113.79999, 114.0, 112.0, 112.12, 4140.27499865], [1376481600000, 112.12, 113.01985, 112.0, 112.1, 718.56643346], [1376485200000, 112.1, 112.56, 110.6, 111.30501, 2485.62159105], [1376488800000, 111.30501, 113.49999, 111.305, 111.62101, 1514.50361916], [1376492400000, 111.62101, 114.0, 111.62101, 112.72192, 2430.5291563], [1376496000000, 112.72192, 115.0, 112.72192, 114.50001, 5109.60220777], [1376499600000, 114.50001, 115.0, 114.0631, 114.9548, 949.95125956], [1376503200000, 114.9548, 114.9548, 114.0631, 114.11111, 409.47123665], [1376506800000, 114.11111, 114.11112, 112.47489, 112.56, 3006.19295907], [1376510400000, 112.56, 113.0, 112.4, 112.98, 331.16447884], [1376514000000, 112.98, 113.33, 112.5, 112.55007, 1539.40698696], [1376517600000, 112.55007, 113.10001, 112.5001, 112.74, 396.17289268], [1376521200000, 112.74, 113.245, 112.561, 112.56206, 175.56897362], [1376524800000, 112.56206, 113.321, 112.0, 112.00006, 1787.07276283], [1376528400000, 112.00006, 112.1, 111.65, 111.67, 1570.55970517], [1376532000000, 111.67, 113.321, 111.67, 112.3552, 297.68931118], [1376535600000, 112.3552, 113.321, 111.71235, 111.72, 287.05288554], [1376539200000, 111.72, 112.0, 111.67, 111.70101, 357.7561186], [1376542800000, 111.70101, 112.90352, 111.65, 111.65, 700.14117647], [1376546400000, 111.65, 111.71, 111.1, 111.10001, 408.65771167], [1376550000000, 111.10001, 111.71, 111.00001, 111.17066, 344.27664871], [1376553600000, 111.17066, 111.7, 111.01001, 111.18, 214.1123536], [1376557200000, 111.18, 111.4999, 110.52, 110.52, 738.49083614], [1376560800000, 110.52, 111.71, 110.5, 110.5, 498.72455093], [1376564400000, 110.5, 111.37193, 110.5, 111.1, 348.29753495], [1376568000000, 111.1, 111.397, 110.0, 110.0, 1381.09234842], [1376571600000, 110.0, 110.5, 109.55626, 109.69897, 430.83852788], [1376575200000, 109.69897, 112.7, 109.0, 111.87, 1578.34543727], [1376578800000, 111.87, 112.48026, 110.55051, 111.2, 766.92839501], [1376582400000, 111.2, 111.45, 110.47, 110.47, 312.87174171], [1376586000000, 110.47, 111.44649, 110.47, 111.22, 129.35182305], [1376589600000, 111.22, 111.43764, 110.5, 110.99993, 139.56243406], [1376593200000, 110.99993, 111.3, 110.4, 111.00101, 311.80361127], [1376596800000, 111.00101, 111.55526, 110.44673, 111.30004, 90.22821133], [1376600400000, 111.30004, 111.99629, 108.78, 110.03854, 1517.69718914], [1376604000000, 110.03854, 110.87994, 110.03854, 110.13354, 76.34656736], [1376607600000, 110.13354, 110.99999, 109.04178, 109.99497, 506.91289003], [1376611200000, 109.99497, 110.0, 109.03, 109.0303, 229.60968924], [1376614800000, 109.0303, 110.0, 109.03, 109.04605, 284.99626242], [1376618400000, 109.04605, 109.9998, 108.60001, 108.60002, 550.71118905], [1376622000000, 108.60002, 109.87, 108.60002, 109.19998, 66.49520148], [1376625600000, 109.19998, 109.865, 108.60001, 108.99995, 390.64359667], [1376629200000, 108.99995, 110.45001, 108.51, 109.95, 277.3987447], [1376632800000, 109.95, 112.3, 108.33001, 109.33624, 3023.13739236], [1376636400000, 109.33624, 110.5, 108.34, 108.95, 456.2648533], [1376640000000, 108.95, 110.5, 108.76003, 109.00014, 524.79416782], [1376643600000, 109.00014, 111.00464, 109.0001, 109.91539, 336.74794938], [1376647200000, 109.91539, 111.00666, 109.8674, 110.055, 165.27747905], [1376650800000, 110.055, 111.14083, 110.055, 110.83499, 184.3244569], [1376654400000, 110.83499, 111.5, 110.53006, 111.5, 257.96726948], [1376658000000, 111.5, 111.5, 109.21, 109.87492, 1046.02043218], [1376661600000, 109.87492, 110.5, 109.434, 109.97493, 227.78431113], [1376665200000, 109.97493, 110.5, 109.0, 110.17, 630.08889842], [1376668800000, 110.17, 110.25843, 108.88249, 109.95, 318.87850336], [1376672400000, 109.95, 110.20113, 108.8, 108.9, 300.54086081], [1376676000000, 108.9, 109.73496, 108.8, 109.399, 210.65512754], [1376679600000, 109.399, 109.9, 108.81, 109.43987, 215.36732513], [1376683200000, 109.43987, 109.96599, 108.51004, 109.09998, 306.34794513], [1376686800000, 109.09998, 111.0, 108.662, 109.995, 597.10804233], [1376690400000, 109.995, 110.36, 109.10943, 109.98974, 132.46602533], [1376694000000, 109.98974, 110.0, 108.21, 108.99438, 1833.85039924], [1376697600000, 108.99438, 109.5, 108.4301, 109.5, 107.15197573], [1376701200000, 109.5, 109.5, 108.52, 108.6, 75.40880595], [1376704800000, 108.6, 109.0, 108.22501, 108.51747, 445.39592043], [1376708400000, 108.51747, 108.9849, 108.225, 108.25, 113.43513621], [1376712000000, 108.25, 108.995, 108.25, 108.995, 20.60045886], [1376715600000, 108.995, 109.5, 108.31011, 109.0, 95.29471204], [1376719200000, 109.0, 109.67, 108.505, 109.52367, 102.90689201], [1376722800000, 109.52367, 109.87669, 108.85504, 109.02002, 59.76245191], [1376726400000, 109.02002, 109.48998, 108.855, 109.0, 107.89099366], [1376730000000, 109.0, 109.05, 108.829, 108.9, 84.66738709], [1376733600000, 108.9, 109.87803, 108.8404, 109.861, 242.20273558], [1376737200000, 109.861, 109.861, 108.86, 109.0, 24.21090623], [1376740800000, 109.0, 109.861, 108.84, 109.49999, 304.7936518], [1376744400000, 109.49999, 109.861, 109.0, 109.113, 195.28229535], [1376748000000, 109.113, 114.0, 109.113, 112.9414, 5795.79616055], [1376751600000, 112.9414, 113.9, 111.5, 113.6, 1194.70237095], [1376755200000, 113.6, 113.6, 111.76078, 112.0, 404.09412892], [1376758800000, 112.0, 112.478, 111.51651, 112.3856, 291.43740794], [1376762400000, 112.3856, 112.9, 112.1, 112.18002, 257.26997755], [1376766000000, 112.18002, 113.0, 112.001, 112.001, 204.67817543], [1376769600000, 112.001, 113.0, 112.001, 112.49999, 128.03778109], [1376773200000, 112.49999, 114.0, 112.02, 112.75, 1278.75568391], [1376776800000, 112.75, 113.75, 112.21225, 113.08592, 526.32549572], [1376780400000, 113.08592, 113.7, 112.7, 112.75, 198.55696982], [1376784000000, 112.75, 113.44999, 112.5, 112.865, 166.90508367], [1376787600000, 112.865, 113.5, 112.5, 113.2, 76.78236838], [1376791200000, 113.2, 113.7, 112.5, 112.53201, 158.52556903], [1376794800000, 112.53201, 113.75, 112.3613, 112.3613, 271.91963021], [1376798400000, 112.3613, 113.51644, 112.1, 112.13249, 197.09918653], [1376802000000, 112.13249, 113.49999, 112.00001, 112.70674, 115.36338539], [1376805600000, 112.70674, 112.70674, 112.00001, 112.49999, 109.43840265], [1376809200000, 112.49999, 112.72, 112.0, 112.00149, 304.5953295], [1376812800000, 112.00149, 114.111, 112.0, 114.091, 1528.80237413], [1376816400000, 114.091, 114.111, 112.55041, 112.91811, 528.69089994], [1376820000000, 112.91811, 114.234, 112.85199, 114.1, 145.66695209], [1376823600000, 114.1, 114.1, 113.0399, 113.75, 191.05010341], [1376827200000, 113.75, 114.5, 113.1, 114.25, 865.28601035], [1376830800000, 114.25, 114.6, 113.16423, 113.218, 409.03704544], [1376834400000, 113.218, 114.69, 113.1814, 114.10002, 969.54366156], [1376838000000, 114.10002, 114.688, 113.3, 113.41696, 596.74604714], [1376841600000, 113.41696, 114.46195, 113.34, 114.0, 94.67851837], [1376845200000, 114.0, 114.66, 113.71911, 114.49999, 814.72518405], [1376848800000, 114.49999, 114.6879, 113.71911, 113.97986, 460.92282619], [1376852400000, 113.97986, 114.19996, 113.35, 114.17, 276.95653585], [1376856000000, 114.17, 114.56, 113.14, 113.79998, 394.86532521], [1376859600000, 113.79998, 113.812, 112.8, 113.81194, 273.76026514], [1376863200000, 113.81194, 114.0, 113.005, 113.07001, 65.93593093], [1376866800000, 113.07001, 113.995, 112.84999, 113.38, 307.58387169], [1376870400000, 113.38, 113.891, 112.75079, 113.70998, 167.60934128], [1376874000000, 113.70998, 113.71, 111.771, 111.77102, 1027.15274445], [1376877600000, 111.77102, 115.54108, 111.77102, 115.54108, 6412.3355264], [1376881200000, 115.54108, 117.81088, 114.31217, 115.50003, 5496.08474912], [1376884800000, 115.50003, 116.22475, 115.09, 116.22475, 1296.20171664], [1376888400000, 116.22475, 120.0, 115.99481, 118.864, 6338.09302068], [1376892000000, 118.864, 120.9, 117.63864, 120.3268, 4432.49525138], [1376895600000, 120.3268, 123.74518, 118.77494, 121.7, 5859.22691842], [1376899200000, 121.7, 122.85, 118.84, 122.00001, 3901.81674746], [1376902800000, 122.00001, 123.4, 119.5, 120.99995, 5242.36683081], [1376906400000, 120.99995, 120.99995, 118.77494, 118.77494, 1439.95106158], [1376910000000, 118.77494, 120.5, 118.77494, 119.59995, 762.78953163], [1376913600000, 119.59995, 119.67, 118.77991, 119.15039, 380.28687689], [1376917200000, 119.15039, 119.15039, 118.01, 118.4, 1037.95492545], [1376920800000, 118.4, 120.5, 118.01, 118.4, 1151.2804698], [1376924400000, 118.4, 119.0, 117.2, 118.26105, 1274.6434576], [1376928000000, 118.26105, 118.5, 117.1, 117.1, 1333.17527783], [1376931600000, 117.1, 118.01001, 116.5, 117.17697, 1134.8622168], [1376935200000, 117.17697, 118.5, 116.67089, 118.0, 906.58543986], [1376938800000, 118.0, 119.77, 118.0, 119.49999, 532.04297356], [1376942400000, 119.49999, 119.77, 118.5, 118.99878, 492.93664412], [1376946000000, 118.99878, 118.99878, 118.0, 118.5, 328.30746881], [1376949600000, 118.5, 118.50101, 118.07251, 118.1707, 327.97256652], [1376953200000, 118.1707, 119.0, 118.17, 119.0, 143.97317695], [1376956800000, 119.0, 119.86, 116.817, 118.0, 1831.39990432], [1376960400000, 118.0, 120.0, 117.50809, 118.87, 1127.7188376], [1376964000000, 118.87, 121.95, 118.74502, 119.01229, 3105.7748469], [1376967600000, 119.01229, 120.47291, 118.20758, 118.99999, 329.18876263], [1376971200000, 118.99999, 121.02209, 118.20759, 120.46098, 453.19545365], [1376974800000, 120.46098, 123.01111, 119.76104, 122.00101, 5781.66824738], [1376978400000, 122.00101, 122.25194, 120.0, 121.5, 936.69063604], [1376982000000, 121.5, 122.4899, 120.204, 120.26985, 793.29668508], [1376985600000, 120.26985, 121.77848, 120.26985, 120.5034, 262.70802229], [1376989200000, 120.5034, 121.3887, 120.2, 120.20306, 342.75264553], [1376992800000, 120.20306, 120.899, 120.13, 120.13, 313.89724032], [1376996400000, 120.13, 120.9, 120.12121, 120.1272, 294.51637865], [1377000000000, 120.1272, 121.0, 118.5, 119.98999, 1568.81490118], [1377003600000, 119.98999, 120.8582, 118.65, 119.99999, 281.65779921], [1377007200000, 119.99999, 120.0, 119.40501, 119.69681, 371.32510407], [1377010800000, 119.69681, 120.51333, 119.51, 120.25999, 427.62473315], [1377014400000, 120.25999, 120.26001, 119.58111, 119.58111, 292.74925244], [1377018000000, 119.58111, 120.26, 119.58111, 119.60002, 472.94399007], [1377021600000, 119.60002, 122.22, 119.60002, 121.73064, 1746.63043258], [1377025200000, 121.73064, 122.0, 120.37583, 121.41981, 424.76296672], [1377028800000, 121.41981, 122.14305, 120.52, 121.00909, 546.1406503], [1377032400000, 121.00909, 122.5, 120.52, 122.38401, 804.17401725], [1377036000000, 122.38401, 122.48399, 121.20003, 122.3919, 383.42850072], [1377039600000, 122.3919, 122.39199, 121.2, 121.21005, 362.91528702], [1377043200000, 121.21005, 124.46, 121.21005, 123.01118, 4244.88640924], [1377046800000, 123.01118, 124.7, 123.0, 123.40204, 842.20280275], [1377050400000, 123.40204, 124.94, 123.1, 124.101, 2422.26322427], [1377054000000, 124.101, 124.14659, 121.0, 122.05, 1697.62835755], [1377057600000, 122.05, 122.67097, 120.0, 120.91505, 1570.00041108], [1377061200000, 120.91505, 121.69993, 119.68162, 120.8599, 1711.51011763], [1377064800000, 120.8599, 122.38725, 120.50001, 121.19893, 450.05701088], [1377068400000, 121.19893, 122.07, 120.76, 120.76604, 395.63020589], [1377072000000, 120.76604, 122.0, 120.765, 121.60194, 211.0984523], [1377075600000, 121.60194, 122.38613, 121.10305, 122.20001, 389.06709437], [1377079200000, 122.20001, 122.4999, 121.45, 121.86001, 288.01559177], [1377082800000, 121.86001, 122.4999, 121.46815, 121.50102, 177.55798569], [1377086400000, 121.50102, 122.4999, 121.11, 121.4832, 442.33038057], [1377090000000, 121.4832, 121.79999, 119.96, 120.51101, 1533.57480789], [1377093600000, 120.51101, 123.99, 119.96, 121.85384, 2797.70033809], [1377097200000, 121.85384, 122.47051, 121.00001, 121.01001, 338.57542382], [1377100800000, 121.01001, 125.0, 121.00001, 123.64011, 4078.5895587], [1377104400000, 123.64011, 123.87806, 122.5809, 122.62, 900.15807861], [1377108000000, 122.62, 124.91388, 122.60148, 123.0, 1916.68696068], [1377111600000, 123.0, 124.929, 123.0, 123.93998, 1204.45992857], [1377115200000, 123.93998, 124.26736, 123.05377, 123.15, 148.97799237], [1377118800000, 123.15, 124.08505, 122.20119, 123.83752, 1316.33297331], [1377122400000, 123.83752, 123.83882, 122.17736, 123.49991, 167.66099506], [1377126000000, 123.49991, 123.98999, 122.0, 123.30002, 329.82336715], [1377129600000, 123.30002, 123.55438, 120.84, 122.0, 2870.16444862], [1377133200000, 122.0, 122.33518, 120.54, 121.88963, 1387.73310186], [1377136800000, 121.88963, 124.49, 121.25, 122.59514, 753.03040482], [1377140400000, 122.59514, 123.43515, 122.52, 123.04002, 118.11905487], [1377144000000, 123.04002, 123.29849, 121.56289, 122.199, 189.76900302], [1377147600000, 122.199, 122.2, 121.6, 121.93, 127.47557776], [1377151200000, 121.93, 122.9811, 121.30002, 121.87187, 349.07106795], [1377154800000, 121.87187, 122.49999, 121.1, 122.24975, 380.13104453], [1377158400000, 122.24975, 122.83994, 121.99, 122.25014, 91.73615068], [1377162000000, 122.25014, 122.97571, 122.25, 122.50002, 111.84780364], [1377165600000, 122.50002, 122.95633, 121.59982, 122.10031, 280.43530173], [1377169200000, 122.10031, 122.89, 122.10031, 122.10501, 161.29666693], [1377172800000, 122.10501, 122.89, 122.1002, 122.50004, 114.88613419], [1377176400000, 122.50004, 122.78569, 122.1002, 122.46002, 396.75225191], [1377180000000, 122.46002, 122.78569, 122.1, 122.10002, 194.04317551], [1377183600000, 122.10002, 122.89, 122.1, 122.88995, 589.58911089], [1377187200000, 122.88995, 122.89, 121.31, 121.44, 619.61425026], [1377190800000, 121.44, 121.71, 121.0, 121.01113, 698.79672269], [1377194400000, 121.01113, 122.49101, 121.0, 121.94999, 393.75126884], [1377198000000, 121.94999, 123.58808, 121.05006, 121.97504, 2056.51558393], [1377201600000, 121.97504, 123.0, 121.79249, 121.98002, 213.64520049], [1377205200000, 121.98002, 122.65499, 121.5, 122.55999, 219.57432998], [1377208800000, 122.55999, 122.55999, 121.5, 121.53026, 222.42306334], [1377212400000, 121.53026, 122.46797, 121.15, 121.99992, 275.27705683], [1377216000000, 121.99992, 121.99998, 120.91, 121.19996, 652.50993529], [1377219600000, 121.19996, 121.90326, 120.8, 120.8, 160.82319737], [1377223200000, 120.8, 121.66866, 120.65, 120.65, 292.44161658], [1377226800000, 120.65, 122.0, 120.61, 120.71, 716.43066187], [1377230400000, 120.71, 121.8848, 120.61999, 120.75998, 186.50778484], [1377234000000, 120.75998, 121.91298, 120.62, 120.8821, 823.93408297], [1377237600000, 120.8821, 121.53907, 120.42792, 120.89997, 774.05414761], [1377241200000, 120.89997, 121.02, 120.42792, 120.42792, 401.32283888], [1377244800000, 120.42792, 120.62001, 118.51, 118.62, 4797.88948985], [1377248400000, 118.62, 120.8231, 118.62, 119.011, 771.87966093], [1377252000000, 119.011, 120.0, 119.011, 119.10001, 223.17850401], [1377255600000, 119.10001, 119.99, 119.011, 119.94902, 288.70529585], [1377259200000, 119.94902, 120.0, 119.21, 119.995, 473.13950181], [1377262800000, 119.995, 120.4, 119.21005, 120.39994, 366.51411245], [1377266400000, 120.39994, 121.0, 120.0, 120.9066, 462.98570049], [1377270000000, 120.9066, 120.9066, 119.62214, 120.11566, 298.18459191], [1377273600000, 120.11566, 120.17346, 119.01, 119.34997, 2177.90342403], [1377277200000, 119.34997, 119.93612, 118.51, 118.87504, 2083.08350903], [1377280800000, 118.87504, 119.45834, 118.51, 118.5202, 558.88380257], [1377284400000, 118.5202, 119.67394, 118.5202, 118.92, 335.22916701], [1377288000000, 118.92, 119.67405, 118.52, 118.8, 301.44357522], [1377291600000, 118.8, 119.47996, 118.706, 118.90008, 136.61719981], [1377295200000, 118.90008, 119.495, 118.51, 118.51, 406.13905431], [1377298800000, 118.51, 119.0, 118.444, 118.51003, 541.17189728], [1377302400000, 118.51003, 119.0, 118.5, 118.5, 155.16235408], [1377306000000, 118.5, 119.0, 118.20001, 118.5, 348.86122048], [1377309600000, 118.5, 119.0, 118.20001, 118.2001, 329.5597526], [1377313200000, 118.2001, 119.0, 118.20001, 118.98993, 358.78898429], [1377316800000, 118.98993, 119.0, 118.20001, 118.99993, 112.79674863], [1377320400000, 118.99993, 119.0, 118.0401, 118.9999, 247.17558305], [1377324000000, 118.9999, 118.9999, 118.1001, 118.80003, 25.22136101], [1377327600000, 118.80003, 118.97983, 118.0401, 118.05, 58.85531626], [1377331200000, 118.05, 118.97919, 118.02222, 118.59994, 259.62740733], [1377334800000, 118.59994, 119.5, 118.02222, 119.17811, 626.21298072], [1377338400000, 119.17811, 119.17999, 118.02, 118.08005, 200.7855981], [1377342000000, 118.08005, 119.198, 118.08003, 118.5, 184.6347964], [1377345600000, 118.5, 119.095, 118.05, 118.99985, 255.6389169], [1377349200000, 118.99985, 118.99998, 118.5, 118.89997, 129.63795153], [1377352800000, 118.89997, 119.781, 118.89997, 119.0998, 345.62917458], [1377356400000, 119.0998, 121.1, 119.09322, 121.1, 1122.45503741], [1377360000000, 121.1, 121.13586, 120.005, 120.98266, 294.80127585], [1377363600000, 120.98266, 121.0, 119.8002, 119.8002, 424.85342603], [1377367200000, 119.8002, 120.5001, 119.8, 120.5, 409.99256968], [1377370800000, 120.5, 121.2, 119.83002, 121.2, 362.23133639], [1377374400000, 121.2, 121.3, 120.12, 120.13006, 693.69481951], [1377378000000, 120.13006, 121.39, 120.13006, 121.25991, 285.14593937], [1377381600000, 121.25991, 121.297, 120.12973, 120.54999, 36.8182182], [1377385200000, 120.54999, 121.0, 119.09321, 119.60255, 1102.24003518], [1377388800000, 119.60255, 120.65886, 119.57001, 119.7, 64.88301263], [1377392400000, 119.7, 121.26, 119.5705, 121.0, 434.05327495], [1377396000000, 121.0, 121.297, 119.14, 119.17001, 521.67461773], [1377399600000, 119.17001, 120.6, 119.14376, 120.00003, 39.98089518], [1377403200000, 120.00003, 121.10401, 120.00003, 120.02005, 110.81941015], [1377406800000, 120.02005, 120.96998, 120.00003, 120.33333, 87.56486699], [1377410400000, 120.33333, 121.38999, 119.83103, 120.30004, 263.97373837], [1377414000000, 120.30004, 120.55556, 119.88, 120.01, 112.64149464], [1377417600000, 120.01, 120.75, 120.01, 120.13009, 54.93330157], [1377421200000, 120.13009, 120.94, 120.13009, 120.94, 39.83704909], [1377424800000, 120.94, 120.95, 120.2, 120.95, 107.03342306], [1377428400000, 120.95, 121.297, 120.23, 121.297, 499.35162075], [1377432000000, 121.297, 121.38999, 120.45121, 120.50002, 218.54687373], [1377435600000, 120.50002, 121.5, 120.50002, 121.39001, 238.40509729], [1377439200000, 121.39001, 121.86, 121.39001, 121.86, 767.89426302], [1377442800000, 121.86, 122.0, 121.66392, 121.99981, 233.96820062], [1377446400000, 121.99981, 122.465, 121.88, 122.46, 575.35274477], [1377450000000, 122.46, 122.46499, 121.85, 122.31544, 445.64761174], [1377453600000, 122.31544, 122.386, 121.9, 122.35, 207.30132752], [1377457200000, 122.35, 122.3875, 121.58, 122.1, 168.35073801], [1377460800000, 122.1, 122.465, 121.59088, 122.465, 208.01436876], [1377464400000, 122.465, 122.68, 122.05, 122.48007, 452.56842515], [1377468000000, 122.48007, 122.6, 121.60836, 122.44988, 133.54121709], [1377471600000, 122.44988, 122.99, 121.6275, 122.11102, 1115.69948702], [1377475200000, 122.11102, 122.75513, 121.39001, 121.83093, 841.35764712], [1377478800000, 121.83093, 122.0, 121.39001, 122.0, 302.06228888], [1377482400000, 122.0, 122.47222, 121.7, 122.33334, 143.96265186], [1377486000000, 122.33334, 122.46729, 121.7, 121.87998, 32.10381856], [1377489600000, 121.87998, 122.38599, 121.7, 122.00003, 64.30453715], [1377493200000, 122.00003, 122.65, 121.4, 122.3, 234.22144621], [1377496800000, 122.3, 122.3, 121.33187, 121.33189, 739.32205875], [1377500400000, 121.33189, 122.39826, 121.22482, 122.33587, 495.46043451], [1377504000000, 122.33587, 122.96996, 121.231, 122.45653, 524.57490757], [1377507600000, 122.45653, 122.46752, 121.32287, 121.99982, 89.61815723], [1377511200000, 121.99982, 122.67, 121.23179, 121.45506, 371.52430056]]
```

You are welcome for your great help~

Comment: You mena something like this http://jsfiddle.net/achG4/4/ ? If yes, only what you need is parsing correct your json to this figure.

Comment: Sebastian Bochan, yes. Same as your script. My problem is there is no gap between the Volume and MACD y-axis. They should be separated by some blank lines. Something wrong with my yAxis settings?

Comment: @SimonWang, just adjust the DIV's height and/or the charts dimensions and the yAxis dimensions to get the spacing you need.

Comment: @wergeld, i know should something wrong with the yAxis setting, but i can not figure it out:(